# What is the type of a class in Dart?

Tags: dart

Since Dart has first order types, what is the type of these types?

Example:

```
createSomething(Type factory) {
  return new factory();
}
```

Where Type should be replaced by what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use type-hints on them, but they are of the type `Type`.

Additional reading:

1. [Proposal for First-class Types](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/proposal-for-first-class-types-in-dart.html)